# How do create a shortcut to get Oracle SQLDeveloper to open and connect to a database

Tags: oracle, command-line, oracle-sqldeveloper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle sqldeveloper - how to connect DB from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883820/oracle-sqldeveloper-how-to-connect-db-from-command-line)

In SQL*Plus, I would have done this:

```
sqlplus user/password@database
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent in SQL Developer?