# Open SQL Developer from command line with parameters (connectstring, user, passwort...)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, keepass

is it possible, to open the Oracle SQL Developer 4 from command-line with parameters (e.g. Connectstring, SID, Host, user, password, ...)?

I want to run it out from KeePass and i want to handover these parameters to access the database.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't using the SQLPlus command line interface be the better choice in that case?

Comment: I want a graphical Application and SQL Developer is defined as the standard-tool in my company.

Comment: Okay, it sounded like you were going for some automated process rather than something that actually requires a GUI.

Comment: okay... no, it is needed for a human manual process ;-)

Comment: Good idea! It should be possible to start it via the command line, but I don't know how to specify the parameters. Had a look at `launcher.sh`, somebody needs to spend some effort with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle sqldeveloper - how to connect DB from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883820/oracle-sqldeveloper-how-to-connect-db-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible with SQL Developer (the GUI), but our command-line interface, SQLcl does support that.

Comment: so, we may have some good news to share on this after version 20.2 is released, stay tuned

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith - do you have an update on this? :)

Comment: Nevermind, found your update here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63692797/700926 - looks good.